# XCode 4 Interface Builder: A better way to work with lots of overlapping views

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, xcode4, interface-builder

In IB I have quite a few views that are shown.  Many of them are hidden when the app loads, but are shown later when buttons are pressed.  This is all fine, but when building this layout in IB it is extremely difficult to layout anything because there are so many overlapping views, some of which are partially transparent (ones that are set to hidden) and other are completely overlapping and covering others. This makes layout very hard.

What is the best method when laying out lots of views like this?  Is there another way to break things up? Or better yet, can I hide a a view completely (like in photoshop) so that I can edit the ones underneath, then turn that layer back on?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will be regarded as helpful or flippant but in my experience this specific scenario almost always highlights an overall design problem I didn't realize until I had trouble building and maintaining it. Re-imagining a simpler view structure not only makes things easier to maintain from an engineering standpoint, but often makes for better user experience. Just a thought from the trenches. Have an up-vote for a thought-provoking question. :-)

Comment: Trust me, the layout and design is very simplistic. It is just that the way IB works with views, it can completely cover other views which makes layout hard. I don't have hundreds of views or anything, but even with 3 views overlapping this is a pain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to hide objects in the canvas, but a useful trick for complex layouts is to double-click an item in the document tree to the left - this selects the item and puts focus on the canvas, you can the use the cursor keys to nudge it about.

This doesnt solve the problem of not being able to see things because there are, for example, five or six labels occupying the same space, but if that is the situation it may be a better idea to have a single label and change its contents in code.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I am constantly doing is double clicking them to give them focus. Just wishing that there was more control, but then again, maybe I am too used to page layout programs and Photoshop.

Comment: It's a good suggestion to have one item and change the contents, but I find that gets messy too when it comes to buttons. Then you would have to change the title _and_ the action. It seems cleaner from a code standpoint to have two different buttons, but messier visually in IB.

Comment: @morningstar : fully agree. You've just got to pick where to have your mess!

Comment: @jrturton I more than agree with you that using on UILabel is a good idea, but this doesn't always work well depending on how the app works.

Answer (score 13):

Another option when trying to select a view that is obscured by another is the shortcut:

**'ctrl' + 'shift'  and  click**

It displays a list of all the views under the cursor.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue for an app I'm building that has an arial-view image of a park with clickable hotspots. When a hotspot is clicked a popup UIview is displayed with information about that spot in the park. I use the same VC/XIB for three parks. This makes the XIB really busy and hard to work with (i.e the same issue that you have) The detail UIViews make it hard to work with the views underneath. My workaround was to pick each detailed UIView that was hiding the part of the XIB I wanted to work on, and add 1000 to the UIView origin.x in the size inspector. This moved those UIViews enough out of the way for me to do what I needed to with the XIB. Then when I was done, I moved them back by x 1000. (I just needed to move them out horizontally to do what I needed to)

I know its clunky but given that XCode does not have a convenient way to hide portions of an XIB - it was the quickest approach I could think of!

Comment: It's unclear in the answer but you can `shift+click` multiple views from the view tree on the left and do them all in one go from the size inspector

Answer (score 1):

One approach to handling overlapping items in IB is:

1. Ensure the groups of items that you want to hide are grouped into Views.
2. Give these Views names: e.g. ViewOptionA, ViewOptionB and ViewOptionC.
   Can do this by clicking on name of view in the tree while it is selected and then typing new name.
3. When you want to hide one of those groups of items:
   a) Select the View by either:
   i) Clicking on it in the tree at the left or
   ii) Ctrl-Shift Clicking in the layout editor and then select the view from the list.

   b) In the Attributes Inspector set Alpha to 0.
4. When you want to unhide one of those groups of items:
   As for 2) but set Alpha back to 1

[You do need to remember to unhide all views before you publish!
If you are forgetful like me then perhaps you could subclass UIView and set Alpha to 1.  I haven't tried this subclassing idea yet.]